# Creating a Blog Comments and Reply section using ASP.NET MVC 4 (nested collections)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a Blog Comment and Reply section and I have these three classes mapped to my DB. The first class holds a collection of related comments to an article, the second class holds a collection of related remarks to the comments:

```
public class Article
{
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set;  }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public CategoryTyp Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Remark> Remarks { get; set; }
}

public class Remark
{
    public int RemarkID { get; set; }
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }
    public string RemarkDetail { get; set; }
    public DateTime RemarkTime { get; set;  }
}
```

And inside my Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetArticle(int id)
{
    var article = db.Articles.Include("Comments").Where(a => a.ArticleID == id).SingleOrDefault();

    return View(article);
}
```

I understand the basis of eager loading but my questions are:

1. How do you implement it when you're pulling data from multiple related tables?
2. What is the best practice of populating it to the View? Once I create a View Model how do I stuff the related collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) With multiple related tables you can have two scenarios:

a) Multiple top level relations: you simply add multiple Include statements (I would suggest using lambda expressions instead of strings for this, to avoid typos).

```
db.Articles
   .Include(a=>a.Comments)
   .Include(a=>a.SomethingElse)
   .FirstOrDefault(a=>ArticleID==id); // Side note: I would suggest this instead of your Where plus SingleOrDefault
```

For these scenarios I always use a helper method like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24703272/352826).

b) Multiple nested related entities:

```
db.Articles
    .Include(a=>a.Comments.Select(c=>c.Remarks)
    .FirstOrDefault(a=>ArticleID==id);
```

2) It's a bit up to you how you pass the data to the views. One best practice I can tell you is that you shouldn't let views lazy load any dependant entities or collections. So your use of Include is correct, but I would even suggest to remove the virtual (deactivate lazy loading) to avoid missing an Include by accident.

Regarding the ViewModels you mention, you are actually not using view models, but your data models. This is OK in most cases, unless you need to format the data somehow or add extra information. Then you would need to create a View Model and map it from the data coming from EF.

Another scenario would be if you used WebAPI or an Ajax Action. In that case, I would suggest to use a DTO (equivalent to a ViewModel) to be able to better control the data returned and its serialization.

One last comment about ViewModels is that if you have heavy entities but you only need a few properties, a good choice is to use Projections, to instruct EF to only load the required properties, instead of the full object.

db.Articles
      .Include(a=>a.Comments)
      .Select(a=>new ArticleDto { Id = a.ArticleID, Title = a.Title })
      .ToListAsync();

This will translate to a "SELECT ArticleID, Title FROM Articles", avoiding returning the article bodies and other stuff that you might not need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.. I'm using EF 4.5 and my Include method only takes a string parameter..  I'm assuming your implementation is from a later version?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using EF 6. I suppose it would be good for you to upgrade if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the relationships with `Include`. For example:

```
var article = db.Articles.Include("Comments.Remarks").Where(a => a.ArticleID == id).SingleOrDefault();
```

I'm not sure what you mean by your second question, though. By issuing this query you already have all the comments and all the remarks for those comments. Therefore, you can access them off of the article instance out of the box:

```
foreach (var comment in article.Comments)
{
    ...

    foreach (var remark in comment.Remarks)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How you handle that with your view model is entirely up to you. You could map the comments/remarks to view models of their own, set them directly on the view model, etc. That's all down to what the needs of your application are, and no one but you can speak to that.